# PySpark - Split the combined key

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a RDD that is structured in this format: 
(MAC_address, dst_ip_address, 1)

Here, 1 means the machine with the MAC_address has accessed the dst_ip_address once. I need to count how many times a specific machine with MAC_address has reached a specific dst_ip_address.

I created a rdd with a combined MAC_address and dst_ip_address as key, and applied reduceByKey to count the times.

```
def processJson(data):
    return ((MAC_address, dst_ip_address), 1)

def countreducer(a,b):
    return a+b

tt = df.map(processJson).reduceByKey(countreducer)
```

I am able to get a RDD ((MAC_address, dst_ip_address), 52)
I need to write the RDD into a Json format like this: 
MAC_address_1: 
   [dst_ip_1: 52],
   [dst_ip_2: 38]
MAC_address_2: 
   [dst_ip_1: 12]

My intuition is to split the combined key first but there is no function to flat a combined key. Thus, I wonder whether the above approach is on the right track.